# For a media-collection database, is it wiser to use a bunch of boolean columns, or redundant rows?

Tags: database

I worded that title poorly, I apologise. I couldn't think of a better wording.

I have a question about database design. Say that I want to make a database representing a video game collection; I want to store in it a list of games I own, or my shop sells, or something along those lines. I want to be able to issue queries like "Which games do I have for Android?" and "What platforms do I own Tetris on?"

I can think of two ways to do this, and I'd like to know if one of them is clearly the superior option and why, because they each seem to have advantages and disadvantages to me.

The first would be a database with one varchar column for the title, and then boolean columns for each possible platform, eg

```
TITLE            |    WINDOWS    |    ANDROID    |    SNES
---------------------------------------------------------
Tetris                   0               1             0
Final Fantasy 3          0               1             1
Scrabble                 1               1             0
```

The other option would be to write a table where there's a row for each title-platform combination, like

```
TITLE            | PLATFORM
----------------------------
Tetris             Android
Final Fantasy 3    Android
Final Fantasy 3    SNES
Scrabble           Android
Scrabble           Windows
```

They each seem to store some unnecessary data, but in different ways. In the first example, I can make my title a primary key to avoid making duplicate entries, which is neat and convenient. On the second example, I'd have to make a composite key to protect against duplicates. But the second example seems like it'd fit prepared statements better (in the PHP PDO library, for one example, you can't tokenise column names in prepared statements, making it more of a pain to write "select * where $_GET['platform'] = 1" type statements).

So which option is smarter?